# how ALU Function code defined in RISC-V ISA?

Tags: encoding, cpu-architecture, riscv, instruction-set

In 'Computer Organization and Design' RISC-V version (by Patterson and Hennessy) [ebook](http://home.ustc.edu.cn/%7Elouwenqi/reference_books_tools/Computer%20Organization%20and%20Design%20RISC-V%20edition.pdf) p1195, it has `ALUControl` module :

```cpp
module ALUControl (
    ALUOp,
    FuncCode,
    ALUCtl
);
  input [1:0] ALUOp;
  input [5:0] FuncCode;
  output reg [3:0] ALUCtl;
  always @* // origin book is `always`
    case (FuncCode) //origin book is `ALUOp <=`
      32: ALUCtl <= 2;  // add
      34: ALUCtl <= 6;  // subtract
      36: ALUCtl <= 0;  // and
      37: ALUCtl <= 1;  // or
      39: ALUCtl <= 12;  // nor
      42: ALUCtl <= 7;  // slt
      default: ALUCtl <= 15;  // should not happen
    endcase
endmodule
```

I understand the ALUCtl encoding from this [doc p4](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ecgebotys/NEW/ECE222/4.Processor.pdf). However, what does the [Function code](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/su06/cse141/slides/s06-1cyc_control-1up.pdf)(i.e. 32,34 listed above) which is in link p6 mean? (the link Function code encoding is same as the encoding in the book )

Comment: The first doc you link to is for RISC V, while the second doc you link to is for MIPS.  That has got to be confusing.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I understand the problem. The COD RISC-V may forget to change the code from [MIPS](https://www.d.umn.edu/~gshute/mips/rtype.xhtml) to RISC-V version. In RISC-V, opcode is instruction[6:0], while MIPS is instruction[5:0].

Comment: I tried to find the appendix A which includes the above code in [official web](https://www.elsevier.com/books-and-journals/book-companion/9780128122754/advanced-content-and-appendices#Advanced%20Content), but not find (also not find in [MIPS](https://booksite.elsevier.com/9780124077263/appendices.php) version of the book ). This is weird. But the above ebook has the appendix (not knowing the source of appendix A.)

Comment: That Verilog module you quote, from the RISC V COD, `ALUControl` FIGURE A.5.15 p1195, is a verbatim copy of the same `ALUControl` FIGURE C.5.16 on C-38 in [Appendix C](https://www.cs.tufts.edu/comp/140/files/Appendix-C.pdf) of the COD Fourth Edition (MIPS).  Obviously, they didn't update it for RISC V.  There's no func[5:0] instead there's func3 and func7.

Comment: Sorry. I made the mistake. The appendix A is in the [printed book](https://bank.engzenon.com/tmp/5e7f7183-219c-4d93-911a-4aaec0feb99b/5dc835ea-b66c-4988-be3f-4d51c0feb99b/Computer_Organization_RiscV_Edition.pdf). The orginal risc-v [book (see p14 of the book online 'Advanced Content')](https://www.elsevier.com/__data/assets/pdf_file/0010/297514/Section-4-13_Advanced.pdf#Section%204.13) says `ALUControl` is 'defined
in Figure B.5.16'.  However, it is about GPU from the [official web](https://www.elsevier.com/books-and-journals/book-companion/9780128122754#Home).

Comment: Thanks. After all, I have understanded the problem although the code not corresponds to risc-v.